# jquery: Embedding font face with jquery?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-plugins, embedded-fonts

As far as I know that embedding font face is only possible with CSS3 (CSS2 but not CSS2.1), and not all browsers are ready for it yet, particularly IE (unless IE9?)...

I wonder if it is possible to use jquery to embed font face? any idea how can I start the code? or any plugin which can do this job?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires that you use Flash as well, but it should be cross-browser compatible (unless of course that browser doesn't support Flash...)

http://hubpages.com/hub/sifr-jquery-fonts

Comment: thanks for this. I will have a look through later and try it out! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Typekit (http://typekit.com/)? It costs money, but that way you can be sure both that the font embedding works and that your use of fonts is properly licensed.

Comment: thanks. had a look. it's very commercial - i think i won't go for it. thanks for mentioning it :-)